# Printing Output to Top of Output Window

Tags: java, netbeans, computer-science

I'm trying to get the 3rd and 4th columns shown in the screenshot to appear at the top of the output window just like the 1st and 2nd columns do. Any ideas? Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class MultiplicationTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double conversion = 1.609 ;
        char line = '|';

        System.out.printf("Miles \t Kilometers %1c \t Kilometers \t Miles\n",line);
        //System.out.printf("%20c",line);

        for(int i = 01; i <= 10; ++i) {
             System.out.printf("%d\t %.3f\t    | %n", i, conversion * i);
        }
        for(int x = 20; x <= 65; x+=5) {
             System.out.printf("\t \t \t  %d\t\t %.3f\t %n", x, x / conversion);
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is concatenate the strings all at once then print them all together instead of individually. You're going to have to calculate the whitespace between each of the columns as it will vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the 2 loops:

```
for (int i = 1, x = 20; i <= 10; ++i, x+=5) {
    System.out.printf("%d\t %.3f\t    | ", i, conversion * i);
    System.out.printf("%d\t\t %.3f\t %n", x, x / conversion);
}
```

You might need to do some preliminary calculations to determine which is larger: the number of lines on left or right.

Output:

```
1    1.609      | 20         12.430  
2    3.218      | 25         15.538  
3    4.827      | 30         18.645  
4    6.436      | 35         21.753  
5    8.045      | 40         24.860  
6    9.654      | 45         27.968  
7    11.263     | 50         31.075  
8    12.872     | 55         34.183  
9    14.481     | 60         37.290  
10   16.090     | 65         40.398
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: @P.Roten Since this answer obviously helped you, please consider upvoting it, and/or accepting it as the solution.